# Laravel 5.1 Passing data (controller -> view)

Tags: laravel-5.1

I'm new to Laravel, I want to understand what is the best approach to share values from controllers to views: I have found few ways of doing it :

1. view()->share('variable_name',$value);
2. session(['variable_name'=>$value]);
3. return view('viewname')->with('variable_name'=>$value);

Is there any difference between these ways?
Also, is it a good practice to share data from the model(from design point of view)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** The best and valid approach, passing data from controller to view is

```
return view('viewname')->with('variable_name'=>$value);
```

data will be accessible in specific page views

**2)** While this is also valid approach, but this case is used, when you want to share your data in all views on any page you access

```
view()->share('variable_name',$value);
```

the above line means, when you access any page, in all pages your `variable_name` will be available **eg**:

```
welcome
contact us
about us
gallery
admin/listing etc
```

**3)** `session()` is used for storing small amount of information across the all website pages. **eg**: we store, user basic information, last login time, redirect url etc(it depends upon requirement), be default session has some expiry time, around 20min, means if you don't do any activity, your session will be expire.

I hope that make sense for you